# How to align form input

Tags: html, css, django, forms, bulma

I'm going crazy trying to align a form with `Django` and `Bulma`. Here is the problem, the input shows misaligned:

[image: form misaligned]

That is what happens, when I try to set the alignment to center. If I align left, the input text shows properly, but not in the center of the screen as I want it. This is the template code. `display:block` was just a try to fix it, but it makes no difference at all.

```
{% for field in wizard.form %}
    <div class="field has-text-centered">
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div>
                <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <label class="label" style="display:block;">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>

        <div class="control has-text-centered" style="display:block;">{{ field }}</div>
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help is-danger">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks a lot for the help, I've been struggling for 1'5 hour with something that seems so relatively simple!

Comment: if you want to center the screen contents, you could just give padding to both side or use flexbox. I think you need to take a little bit more into CSS.

Comment: I think flexbox is the best here for responsiveness in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I definitely need to get better at CSS. I tried looking at the documentation of Bulma, which uses flexbox. But I think the problem resides in the way I'm looping through the form, when I solve the issue for one input it gets broken for another. The form template is used in very different forms (about 250 questions). So I desisted and changed the layout for another that is easier for me to do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to limit the wrapper div with max-width and set its left and right margin to auto.

That means that children elements are going to be aligned left, but the parent element is going to be centered.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried playing with the max width and margins as you suggested, but I wasn't able to make it look good on every type of answer. The form template is used in a long form, which has a lot of answers (some 0 characters long, others several lines), so if I added the margin in the short answers it worked, but in the long ones it didn't. I ended up changing the layout for another that was easier to do with my limited skills :) . Thanks again for the help!